# Using a class function as an event listener in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, listener, dom-events

I have the following code:

```
context
    .on( 'hangup', this.handleHangup );
```

In the class constructor and

```
PlayMessage.prototype.handleHangup = function() {
    log.callout.info( "Call [%s]: Client hungup.", this.row.get( 'id' ) );
    this.endCall(); // Get out of here
}
```

As a function to the class. The class is called PlayMessage.

I get an error saying:

> events.js:130
>       throw TypeError('listener must be a function');

Talking about the context.on( ... ) line I pasted above.

How should I be using the class function as a listener?

Comment: What is the value of the `this` keyword when you call `context.on( 'hangup', this.handleHangup );`?

Comment: If you have problems debugging node.js code have a look at [https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_debugger](https://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html#debugger_debugger).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, when passing functions to event handlers that rely on a bound context (`this`) like prototype methods, you have to manually bind the context before passing.

```
context
    .on( 'hangup', this.handleHangup.bind(this) );
```

This ensures that the `this` value within `handleHangup` is the instance of the "class" you expect.

[More info on the `Function` method `.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I was trying to declare a class without "new" so none of the prototyped functions existed. That's an amazing learning experience for me.